# Как обрезать многострочный текст что бы в конце стояли

Tags: jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.description {
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 25px 10px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 height: 135px;
  width: 100px;
 position: relative;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="description"><a href="https://allescortsankara.com/girl/vera/" title="Vera" data-wpel-link="internal"></a><a href="/">test test testes tsets test test testes tsets test test testes tsets test test testes tsetstest test testes tsets test test testes tsets  test test testes tsetstest test testes tsets .</div>
```

Работать должно в браузерах хром, опера, гугл.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Работает только в хроме. В остальных браузерах нет
не работает. После обрезки этот текст должен оставаться в коде

Comment: Приведите пример кода. Непонятно в какой ситуации не работает. Рабочий пример есть на http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow

Comment: в хроме [работает](https://image.prntscr.com/image/vMDfkVsNS5W_acPXga4Qkw.png). В чем именно у Вас не работает `ellipsis` (браузер, версия) ?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Нужно обрезать текст длиной более определенного количества знаков и ставить в конце многоточие?

Comment: Текст определенной высоты на последнем предложении в конце стоят точки. 
text-overflow: ellipsis; работает только для однострочного текста.
Этот код работает в хроме но в мозиле и опере ничего. display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так ? [источник](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rqoRMz?editors=1100)

```js
var size = 120,
    newsContent= $('.news-content'),
    newsText = newsContent.text();
    
if(newsText.length > size){
 newsContent.text(newsText.slice(0, size) + ' ...');
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext);

body{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #99aaad;
}
.bx-content{
 width: 600px;
 padding: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #a8b3b5;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 100px auto;
}
.news-content{ line-height: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
h1{ margin-top: 0; color: #52686c; }
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bx-content">
 <h1>Каким способом можно обрезать текст с троеточием в конце?</h1>
 <div class="news-content">Добрый день! Интересует вопрос как можно обрезать текст, чтобы в конце всегда было троеточие. Вариант с подставлением туда рисунка с градиентным фоном не выход. CSS свойство {text-overflow: ellipsis} тоже не помогает, так как оно работает с одной строчкой, у меня же блок с текстом на 5-6 строк. Посоветуйте по возможности более-менее детальную инфу как это сделать. Спасибо за ответ.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну чистенький вариант. Единственное: автор просил что бы текст "оставался в коде". Не уверен что имелось в виду но если я прав то ваш вариант обрезает лишний текст и не подойдет.

Comment: Да, текст должен остаться в коде. Как сделать что бы показывало обрезанный текст а в коде полный??

Comment: @Telion  в каком коде ? Он же и так в html есть - где он должен остаться ?

Comment: То есть если обрезать так текст поисковики будут видить полный текст??

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой, костыльный, вариант.

```js
var lineClamp = (5*18); // 5 строчек, одна строчка ~18px

$('.description a').each(function(){
  var thisHeight = $(this).height();
  if(thisHeight>lineClamp){
    $(this).addClass('description-big-size').height(lineClamp);
  }
});
```

```css
.description {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 135px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.description a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.description-big-size {position: relative;}
.description-big-size::after {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------->
<div class="description">
  <a href="https://allescortsankara.com/girl/vera/" title="Vera" data-wpel-link="internal"></a>
  <a href="/">test test testes tsets test test testes tsets test test testes tsets test test testes tsetstest test testes tsets test test testes tsets  test test testes tsetstest test testes tsets .</a>
</div>

<div class="description">
  <a href="https://allescortsankara.com/girl/vera/" title="Vera" data-wpel-link="internal"></a>
  <a href="/">test test testes tsets testtest test testes tsets test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: работает только для однострочного текста. Мне нужно что бы было несколько строк

Comment: Тогда только скриптами.

Comment: @Vlad467, обновил ответ на костыль.